# Selenium Configuration with Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run simple selenium webdriver case on Eclipse but it's throwing errors.

My code:

```
package automationFramework;



import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          String MyURL = "http://www.google.com";

           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(MyURL);

            //close Firefox
            driver.close();

            // exit the program explicitly
            System.exit(0);

    }

}


Following lines are errors.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: VISTA
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'VW003419', ip: '10.68.30.32', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at automationFramework.Demo.main(Demo.java:16)
```

It's happening with chrome as well. I have installed it on default location.

Comment: I have added Jar files successfully .. That's not the problem

Comment: hi as per error selenium is not able to find firefox on your system is firefox installed on your system

Comment: @AkashDugam Do you have Firefox on your machine?

Comment: Yes.. Even it's located in C drive ...

Comment: Even tried with Chrome (that too installed in my system) throwing same error :(

Comment: For chrome you need to add a separate binary file. Is firefox installed in the default location or did you change the location of Firefox while installing?

Comment: Add your code and the error message as _text_, remove the image then. Edit your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to open chrome like below

```
// call the Chrome driver as below first 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\eclipseProject\\##\\src\\com\\##\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
// path to chrome exe that you have downloaded form given url (below)
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.com"); // link to your web-table web page
```

// download chrome exe form this link http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: ok m glad that it get resolved if you think my answer helped you then plz mark it as your answer thhanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Personal");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                 //Launch the Online Store Website
                driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

                // Print a Log In message to the screen
                System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

                //Wait for 5 Sec
                Thread.sleep(5);

                // Close the driver
                driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Exception Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: D:\Personal
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at First.main(First.java:12)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make your formatting better for ease of reading

Comment: Is this an answer or a new question?